# Connecting to Bluetooth DUAL-SPP using RFcommsocket

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to use BluetoothConnectionService written by Mitch Tabian to connect to a Microchip BM77 dual mode module.  I am trying to connect with transparent BT.

From the logcat it seems that it can not connect to the UUID and then closes socket.

Is this BM77 device not able to connect using RFcommsocket?  Does it require a different UUID?

```
package com.example.user.bluetooth_communication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by User on 12/21/2016.
 */

public class BluetoothConnectionService {

private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
Context mContext;

private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private UUID deviceUUID;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    start();
}


/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread(){
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try{
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

            Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run(){
        Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        try{
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

            socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

            Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        //talk about this is in the 3rd
        if(socket != null){
            connected(socket,mmDevice);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}

/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
        mmDevice = device;
        deviceUUID = uuid;
    }

    public void run(){
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                    +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();

            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
        }

        //will talk about this in the 3rd video
        connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}



/**
 * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
 */
public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}

/**

 AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
 Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
 **/

public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
    Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

    //initprogress dialog
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
            ,"Please Wait...",true);

    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
    mConnectThread.start();
}

/**
 Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
 receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
 **/
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
        try{
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 *
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;

    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
    //perform the write
    mConnectedThread.write(out);
}

   }


    D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0
D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery
D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery = true
D/MainActivity: onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.
D/MainActivity: onItemClick: deviceName = Dual-SPP
                onItemClick: deviceAddress = 34:81:F4:40:0F:2A
                Trying to pair with Dual-SPP
I/BluetoothDevice: createBond() for device 40:0 called by pid: 27565 tid: 27565
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: start
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: AcceptThread Running.
                           run: RFCOM server socket start.....
D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/MainActivity: startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection.
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: startClient: Started.
D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: setView = DecorView@be25176[Connecting Bluetooth] TM=true MM=false
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectThread: started.
I/BluetoothConnectionServ: RUN mConnectThread 
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery
D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery = true
D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[23,790][1057,1349] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 524643803136} changed=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7a27b171e0
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(23, 790 - 1057, 1349) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@3daba6f, channel: -1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@9c9637c, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@4f75405mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@9c67c5a impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@b028e8b fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@2073b68, mSocketState: INIT
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: Closed Socket.
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
                           connected: Starting.
                           ConnectedThread: Starting.
D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7a27b171e0
D/ViewRootImpl@fcf1c11[Connecting Bluetooth]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputEventReceiver: channel '48033aa Connecting Bluetooth (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
D/InputEventReceiver: channel '48033aa Connecting Bluetooth (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
D/ViewRootImpl@21bc2e2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error reading Input Stream. socket closed
```

Comment: Bluetooth (BT) Dual Mode: does it mean it can simultaneously run BT in both modes: BT Classic and BT Low-Energy (Energy) or just only one mode in a configured hardware setup? Need to be clear on this.

Comment: The standard BT Classic RFCOMM/SPP profile UUID string is `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` if you want to make a serial connection between your app and a serial device over BT.